# Removing a submanifold from a closed manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a simply-connected closed manifold. Can we find a closed submanifold $N \subsetneq M$ such that $M\backslash N$ is simply-connected and has finite second homotopy group?

Comment: I might be out of my depth there, but if $M$ has a [handlebody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handlebody) [decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_decomposition) and you take $N$ to be the union of all the attaching boundaries, then $M\setminus N$ is just a disjoint union of balls, right? If you don't require $M\setminus N$ to be connected, this might fit your criteria.

Comment: What dimensions are you thinking of? And do you mean for $N$ to be connected?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Yes, I also require $M\backslash N$ to be connected.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie $M$ has general dimension $n$, and $N$ is not assumed to be connected.

Comment: What about choosing $N$ as the complement of a small open ball ? Then $M\setminus N$ is that open ball and hence simply connected and has a finite second homotopy group?

Comment: Ah sorry. Closed means without boundary.

Comment: Which manifold $N$ works for $M=S^2\times S^2$ ?

Comment: @HenrikRüping I believe that the subspace $\{(v, \pm v) | v \in S^2\}$ works in that case.

Comment: @HenrikRüping: Maybe it should be done dually (in your example you indeed have to remove $pt\times S^3$. Find a homology class in $H^{n-2}(M)$ such that the intersection product with the class you want to remove is $1$. Classes in $H^{n-2}(M)$ are representable by submanifolds. What happens if we remove this submanifold?

Comment: @TylerLawson I dont think that subspace works either. Then $M\setminus N$ is a bundle over $S^2$. I think we can identify it with the open disc bundle in the tangent bundle over $S^2$ minus the zero section as follows. For a point $(v,w)$ pick the tangent vector at $v$ pointing towards $w$ of length $d(v,w)$. 
This open disc bundle should be homotopy equivalent to the unit tangent bundle, which is $\mathbb{R}P^3$. Hence $\pi_2$ is correct, but $M\setminus N$ is not simply connected.

Comment: @HenrikRüping You are of course correct; I had forgotten that condition. I believe that, as a result, the only remaining possibility would be removing some nonorientable 3-dimensional submanifold.

Answer (score 7):

Following Henrik Rüping's suggestion: if you take $M = S^2\times S^2$, you cannot find any $N$ doing the trick. I'll work with homology with integer coefficients.

By excision and Poincaré–Lefschetz duality, $H_k(M,N) \cong H^{4-k}(M\setminus N)$ (and note that this does not use any orientability assumption on $N$). Since $M\setminus N$ is connected, $H_4(M,N) = \mathbb{Z}$. Since $M\setminus N$ is simply-connected, $H_3(M,N) = 0$. By Hurewicz, since $\pi_2(M\setminus N)$ is finite, $H_2(M\setminus N)$ is finite, too, and by the universal coefficient theorem we have $H_2(M,N) = 0$.

Look at the long exact sequence of the pair $(M,N)$, with the input from above.
$$0 \to H_4(N) \to H_4(M) \to H_4(M,N) \to H_3(N) \to 0,$$
so $H_4(N) = 0$ and $H_3(N) = 0$.
$$0 = H_3(M,N) \to H_2(N) \to H_2(M) \to H_2(M,N) = 0,$$
so $H_2(N) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ and the map into $H_2(M)$ is an isomorphism.
$$0 = H_2(M,N) \to H_1(N) \to H_1(M) = 0,$$
so $H_1(N) = 0$.

So $N$ cannot have any orientable 3-manifold component (ok, this we knew for otherwise it'd disconnect) and no 1-dimensional component. $N$ cannot have a 3-dimensional component $Y$ (which is necessarily non-orientable), because non-orientable 3-manifolds have $b_1(Y) > 0$ (since $\chi(Y) = 0$ and $H_3(Y) = 0$).

So $N$ has to be a union of surfaces, which necessarily are two 2-spheres, since $H_2(N) = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $H_1(N) = 0$. Moreover, $H_2(N)$ is generated by the fundamental classes of the two 2-spheres. But this contradicts the fact that $H_2(N) \to H_2(M)$ is an isomorphism *over the integers*, for the intersection form of $H_2(M)$ is not diagonalisable over $\mathbb{Z}$, so you can not disjointly embed two 2-spheres so that their fundamental classes generate $H_2(M)$.

Answer (score 3):

A small variation on Tyler's suggestion works.

Let $M=S^3 \times S^3$ and the submanifold $N$ be either the diagonal $N = \{ (p,p) : p \in S^3 \}$ or the anti-diagonal $N = \{ (p,-p) : p \in S^3 \}$, then $M \setminus N$ is a copy of the tangent bundle $TS^3$, which is simply connected with a finite (trivial) second homotopy group.

A version of Tyler's example works in dimension $5$, let $M = S^2 \times S^3$ and let $f : S^3 \to S^2$ be any smooth function, then $N = \{ (f(p), p) : p \in S^3 \}$ works.  The exterior of $N$ in $M$ is a $2$-dimensional vector bundle over $S^3$.  Perhaps the Hopf fibration would be the most interesting case, but the constant function also works.

Here is an $n$-manifold example.  $M= S^n$ with $N=\{*\}$, i.e. remove a single point from the $n$-sphere.  The complement is a copy of $\mathbb R^n$, which is contractible.  This works provided $n \geq 2$.

My impression is the symbol $N \subsetneq M$ is used to mean $N$ is a subset but not equal to $M$.  So in principle you could just choose $N=\emptyset$ (empty) and let $M$ be any simply connected closed manifold with finite $\pi_2 M$.  But perhaps you use $N \subsetneq M$ to mean proper submanifold, i.e. not allowed to be empty, either.